# Viewing extended file properties via command line in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, properties

In Windows it is possible to open explorer and add columns to view additional information about a file.  For example in the image below, I added the columns for Company, Copyright and Description:

[image]

I need to know if there is a way to obtain this information via command line on a system running linux (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS).  I can use *strings* and grep for the company name and see that, but, it assumes I already know the company name.  I can't just grep for "Company" and have it return the company name on the same or next line.

Comment: Try to run `nm file`. As for license/copyright and description - you can know it from your package manager (I don't know how to do it in ubuntu).

Comment: Tried that, returned `nm: <filename>: no symbols` on multiple files that I can see in windows that have properties I am looking for as described above.

Comment: Clarify: you want to watch properties of binary & library files *in Ubuntu* or *in windows*?

Comment: I need to be able to see them on Linux (in this instance, my server is running Ubuntu).  I can see the properties on a Windows system, this is how I am trying to find them on Linux.  I know what they are in Windows, I am just trying to find a way to see the same information in Linux.

Comment: run `strings file`. (but I think, you're playing the fool)

Comment: using strings, I can see the data I want.  The problem with this is that if I hadn't known what the company name was before running strings, I might not know that information just looking at the output of strings.  In several files I looked at the information appeared to be there, and in some, it wasn't.  Unfortunately, I don't think I can rely on strings alone to always have the information I need/want.

Answer (score 8):

You can't get all the information with `ls`.

You need several commands:

- **Name**: `ls`
- **Owner**: `ls -ld <filename> | cut -f3 -d' '`

  For example: `root`
- **Date modified**: `ls -ld <filename> | awk '{print $6" "$7}'`

  For example: `2012-03-02 06:56`

  (Use `stat <filename>` for date accessed and changed.)
- **Type**: `file <filename>`

  For example: `/lib/libiw.so.30: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386 (...)`
- **Size**: `ls -hld <filename> | cut -f5 -d' '`

  For example: `34K`
- **Tags**: N/A
- **Company**: `apt-cache show $(dpkg -S <filename> | cut -f1 -d:) | grep Origin`

  For example: `Origin: Ubuntu`

  (On .rpm-based systems this information can be found in `rpm -q -i -f <filename>`)
- **Copyright**: `cat /usr/share/doc/$(dpkg -S <filename> | cut -f1 -d:)/copyright 2>/dev/null || echo 'No copyright information'`

  For example: `(...) Copyright: Commercial (...)`

  (On .rpm-based systems this information can be found in `rpm -q -i -f <filename>`)
- **Description**: `apt-cache show $(dpkg -S <filename> | cut -f1 -d:) | fgrep 'Description' | fgrep -v Description-md5`

  For example: `Description-en: Filesystem in Userspace (library)`

  (On .rpm-based systems this information can be found in `rpm -q -i -f <filename>`)
- **Long description**: `apt-cache show $(dpkg -S <filename> | cut -f1 -d:) | egrep -v '^[^ ]'`

  For example:  `GNU findutils provides utilities to find files meeting specified
  criteria and perform various actions on the files which are found.
  This package contains 'find' and 'xargs'; however, 'locate' has
  been split off into a separate package.`

  (On .rpm-based systems this information can be found in `rpm -q -i -f <filename>`)

This is a very quick and dirty shell function for Ubuntu that provides much of the information above:

```
function lsw { filename=$1; ( echo "XXNameXXOwnerXXDate ModifiedXXTypeXXSizeXXCompanyXXDescription"; ( echo  XX$filename; echo -n XX; ls -dl $filename | cut -f3 -d' '; echo -n XX; ls -dl $filename | awk '{print $6" "$7}'; echo -n XX; file $filename | cut -f2 -d: | cut -f1 -d,; echo -n XX; ls -hld $filename| cut -f5 -d' '; echo -n XX; apt-cache show $(dpkg -S $filename 2>/dev/null| cut -f1 -d:) 2>/dev/null| egrep 'Origin:|Section:' | tail -n 1 | cut -f2 -d:; echo -n XX; apt-cache show $(dpkg -S $filename 2>/dev/null| cut -f1 -d:) 2>/dev/null| fgrep 'Description' | fgrep -v Description-md5 | cut -f2 -d:) | tr '\n' ' '; echo ) | column -t -s XX; }
```

Some examples:

```
$ lsw /home/jaume
Name          Owner   Date Modified      Type         Size   Company  Description
/home/jaume   jaume   2013-02-19 22:01    directory   4.0K 

$ lsw /opt/ibm/notes/notes
Name                   Owner  Date Modified      Type                         Size  Company  Description
/opt/ibm/notes/notes   root   2012-12-08 08:47    ELF 32-bit LSB executable   47K    IBM      IBM Notes 

$ lsw /lib/libfuse.so.2
Name                Owner  Date Modified      Type                                   Size  Company   Description
/lib/libfuse.so.2   root   2012-03-02 16:33    symbolic link to `libfuse.so.2.8.6'   16     Ubuntu    Filesystem in Userspace (library)
```